# Using RFIDs (OMNIKey 6321) With Java

Tags: java, rfid, mifare

For my Undergraduate Thesis, I am using RFID's to tag and document Patient information. My advisor ordered my hardware for me. He picked an OMNIKEY 6321 and Mifare cards. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get these working. If anyone has advice or can point me in the right direction, that would be much appriciated.

Comment: do you have a SDK from OMNIkey?

Comment: I did not receive one with my hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Java natively supports Omnikey with Mifare - "import javax.smartcardio.*". Examples of the application and developers guide is on HIDglobal website.

Comment: I have found a few examples of programs using "import javax.smartcardio.*", but nothing on HIDglobal's website.